# Remove line numbers from text file and extract values to list

Tags: python, list, file, text

I have a txt file with some data but they are have line number annotations, how can I easily go from this to list with only the numbers on the right?

```
1   3.170

2   3.198

3   3.188

4   3.153

5   3.164

6   3.214

7   3.095

8   3.078

9   3.193

10  3.113
```

I've done it in 3 steps:

```
with open('numbers', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        for word in line.split():
            print(word)
```

then with the result

```
with open('main.py') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
print(lines)
```

Then I sorted the numbers and just copied the value between 3 and 4:

```
numbers = ('1', '3.170', '2', '3.198', '3', '3.188', '4', '3.153', '5', '3.164', '6', '3.214', '7', '3.095', '8', '3.078', '9', '3.193', '10', '3.113', '11', '3.153', '12', '3.119')
float_lst = [float(item) for item in numbers]
sor = sorted(float_lst)
print(sor)
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: when you read the file by-lines, you can throw away the first part (or perhaps compare it to the index from `enumerate(fh, 1)` to see that the lineno is consistent before you do)

Comment: post your expected output or desired output

Comment: I edited to clean up but I had to guess some things. Does your actual input file have empty lines between the data lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just discard the line numbers as you go.

```py
with open('numbers', 'r') as file:
    numbers = [float(line.rstrip('\n').split()[1]) for line in file]
```

If the list comprehension seems intimidating, here's a longhand version:

```py
numbers = []
with open('numbers', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        # Trim trailing newline
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        # Extract last item
        item = line.split()[1]
        # Convert to float, add to list
        numbers.append(float(item))
```

As a general principle, don't carry with you data that you don't need.

If some lines could be empty, you can add an `if not line: continue` condition in the longhand version after removing the newline.

```py
numbers = []
with open('numbers', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        # Trim trailing newline
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        # Skip empty lines
        if not line:
            continue
        # Extract last item
        item = line.split()[1]
        # Convert to float, add to list
        numbers.append(float(item))
```

Comment: What do I do wrong if my list index is out of range?

Comment: It probably means you have some lines without line numbers (entirely empty, perhaps?) See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're making this way harder than it needs to be.

```
for line in open('numbers'):
    print( float(line.rstrip().split()[1]) )
```